# How to speed up loading text file to multi vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have to load large files (several GB) with data and I want to load them to two dimensional vector. Code below does the job, but it is insanely slow. To be more specific, the goal is to get all lines where values in 2nd column are equal to index(_lh,_sh). And then exclude the lines where 4th column value is same as line+1 and line-1.
Now, I'am new to c++ and I usualy code in Python (have working code for this problem already). But I need it to be as fast as posible so I tried to rewrite my python code to C++. But it rus slower than Python now (and only getting the data to vector is implemented)... so before I proceed, I want to improve that.
From what I have found in similar questions, the problem would be dynamic vectors, .push_back() and getline().

I am rather confused about maping and chunk loading mentioned in similar questions so I am not able to change the code acording to these.

Could you help me to optimize this code?

Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int pixel(int radek, int sloupec, int rozmer = 256) {
    int index = (radek - 1) * rozmer + sloupec;
    int index_lh = (index - rozmer - 1);
    int index_sh = (index - rozmer);
    int index_ph = (index - rozmer + 1);
    int index_l = (index - 1);
    int index_p = (index + 1);
    int index_ld = (index + rozmer - 1);
    int index_sd = (index + rozmer);
    int index_pd = (index + rozmer + 1);
    array<int, 9> index_all = { {index, index_lh, index_sh, index_ph, index_l, index_p, index_ld, index_sd, index_pd } };
    vector<vector<string>> Data;
    vector<string> Line;
    string line;

    for (int m = 2; m < 3; m++) {
        string url = ("e:/TPX3 - kalibrace - 170420/ToT_ToA_calib_Zn_" + to_string(m) + string(".t3pa"));
        cout << url << endl;
        ifstream infile(url);
        if (!infile)
        {
            cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return -1;
        }
        while (getline(infile, line))
        {
            Line.push_back(line);
            istringstream txtStream(line);
            string txtElement;
            vector<string> Element;
            while (getline(txtStream, txtElement, '\t')){
                Element.push_back(txtElement);
            }
            Data.push_back(Element);
        }
    }
    cout << Data[1][0] << ' ' << Data[1][1] << ' ' << Data[1][2] << endl;
    return 0; 
}

int main()
{   
    int x = pixel(120, 120);
    cout << x << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Boost has some libraries for *very* fast read/write I/O operations. If you can use them of course.

Comment: Doesn't `for (int m = 2; m < 3; m++)` mean the loop only goes once? Is that intentional?

Comment: What is slow? The loading from file to the 2D array or your search?

Comment: InternetAussie - yes.. it goes only once. In final code I want to go through all files, but for testing I use only one smaller.

arynaq - I'm not sure... But I guess both needs to be handeled.

Comment: Streams in C++ are one of the slowest ways to process files, especially when using formatted input/output operations. If you want max. throughput with streams, open file in binary mode (`std::ios::binary`), use only unformatted operations (e. g. `istream::read()`) and assign a large buffer by calling `stream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf( buffer, size )`. Or get rid of streams and use C file API (`fopen()`, `fread()`, ...). Use the profiler to find further bottlenecks.

Answer (score 2):

Vectors can get slow if their underlying buffer gets reallocated often. A vector is required to be implemented on a buffer of continuous memory, and every time the buffer limit is exceeded, it will have to allocate a new and larger buffer, and then copy the content from the old buffer to the new buffer. If you have an idea of how big buffers you require (you don't need to be excact), you can help the program to allocate a buffer of appropriate size by using e.g. `Data.reserve(n)` (where `n` is approximately the number of elements you think you need). This does note change the "size" of the vector, just the size of the underlying buffer. As a concluding remark, I have to say I haven't really ever benchmarked this, so this may or may not improve the performance of your program.

EDIT: Though, I deem it a bit more likely that the performance is a bit bottled by the line `Data.push_back(Element);` which makes a copy of the Element-vector. If you're using C++11, I believe it's possible to work around this by doing something like `Data.emplace_back(std::move(Element));` in which case you can't alter `Element` afterwards (it's content is moved). You would also need to include `memory` for `std::move`.

Comment: This helped a bit. Before the code run 400k lines and 6 columns in 1:40 min. Now it is 1:01 min... but still slow.
To compare Python finish in 8.7s with data outpout to file.

Comment: Ok... with your next suggestion It now runs 45s. Used `move` for both, `Element` and `Data` and deleted `Line.push_back(line);` (forgot to delete it from previous tries).

Comment: It's interesting that it seems to be necessary to start using c++ tricks to even get close to the speed of a python implementation for these kind of things :P And c++ that is supposed to be fast. If you are not using any io-functions from C, you can try to make a call to `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`, I've experienced that this _can_ speed up the streams quite considerably.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using old C file reading API (`FILE*`, `fopen()`, etc.) or setting a bigger buffer for `std::istringstream` as follows

```
constexp std::size_t  dimBuff { 10240 } // 10K, by example
char myBuff[dimBuff];

// ...

istringstream txtStream(line);
txtStream.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(myBuff, dimBuff);
```

Another thing that you can try is using `std::deque`s instead of `std::vector`s (but I've no idea if this is useful).

As suggested by muos, you can use move semantics; you can use `emplace_back()` also.

So I suggest to try with

```
Element.push_back(std::move(txtElement));

Data.push_back(std::move(Element));
```

or

```
Element.emplace_back(std::move(txtElement));

Data.emplace_back(std::move(Element));
```

You can also swith the following lines (there isn't a move constructor from a string for `std::istringstream`, if I'm not wrong)

```
Line.push_back(line);
istringstream txtStream(line);
```

adding move semantics (and `emplace_back()`)

```
istringstream txtStream(line);
Line.emplace_back(std::move(line));
```

p.s.: obviously `reserve()` is usefull

Comment: Already did that from mous answer. It helped, but Python is still 6 times faster.

Comment: @Pedro - anser improved with a couple of other suggestions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop, you could try changing the lines from

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    Line.push_back(line);
    istringstream txtStream(line);
    string txtElement;
    vector<string> Element;
    while (getline(txtStream, txtElement, '\t')){
        Element.push_back(txtElement);
    }
    Data.push_back(Element);
}
```

to:

```
while (getline(infile, line))
{
    Line.push_back(line);
    istringstream txtStream(line);
    string txtElement;
    //vector<string> Element; [-]
    Data.emplace_back(); // [+]
    while (getline(txtStream, txtElement, '\t')) {
        //Element.push_back(txtElement); [-]
        Data.back().push_back(txtElement); // [+]
    }
    //Data.push_back(Element); [-]
}
```

That way, the vectors in `Data` don't need to get moved or copied there -- they are already constructed, albeit empty. The vectors in `Data` are default-constructed with `.emplace_back()`. We get the last element in `Data` with the `.back()` function, and push our values as usual with `.push_back()`. Hopefully this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `reserve(int)` on the vectors so they are created closer to the target size.

That too can avoid a lot of vector hopping around the heap, as the vector will only be recreated of it passes the target size.

You can call reserve again if vector passes the size you previously reserved:

```
vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10);
for (int i=0;i < 1000; i++)
{
    if ( vec.size() == vec.capacity() )
    {
        vec.reserve(vec.size()+10);

    }
    vec.push_back(i);
}
```